# Find if variable exists in json file or not

Tags: php, json

I want to know how can I make a condition if a variable exist in a json file or not .Sometimes I get a file with error attribute and sometimes not.All depends of what Iam writing in my url address. SO I need to make this condition.
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code, example data, etc.? If you have `$json` holding your JSON data, can't you just use `isset($json["variable"])` ?

Comment: post the json, your code, any error message you are getting and what you have tried to correct it. Otherwise, any answer to this question would be a pure guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the content of the JSON file using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://example.com/example.json/');
```

Now decode the JSON using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
```

You have an associative array containing all the information. To check some property you need just:

```
if (isset($json['<key>'])){
  // Do something
}
```